# cloning object on linq grouping - copy constructor substitute

Tags: linq, group-by, copy-constructor

I have collection of custom objects(assets) which I want to group with LINQ.
Custom object has standard properties like id, name and cost property.
When grouping I want to calculate cost for each group, so I'm using little trick like this:

```
from a in assets
group a by a.AssetId into ga
select new Asset()
                 {
                    AssetId = ga.Key,
                    Cost = ga.Select(gg=>gg.Cost).Sum()
                 }
```

Ok, everything is fine here. But...in order to initialize order properties as well, I'm using copy contructor and cost calculations together...

```
from a in assets
group a by a.AssetId into ga
select new Asset(ga.FirstOrDefault())
                 {
                    AssetId = ga.Key,
                    Cost = ga.Select(gg=>gg.Cost).Sum()
                 }
```

So now, I get collection of grouped assets by id, with all properties copied from a first asset in a group with calculated grouped cost. But...in order to do that I need to write for every object that using this kind of grouping, a copy constructor with 'all properties initialization' which in my case is overhead because there are objects with 20+ properties.

I've tried to use clone trick from a link:

[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)

in linq group query but with no success.

My question: is there a better/more elegant way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need deep copy them you can use MemberwiseClone method. The implementation (comes from Object class) & gives you a shallow copy. So line `new Asset(ga.FirstOrDefault())` 
will become `((Asset)(ga.FirstOrDefault().MemberwiseClone()))`.
However, being shallow copy, [First Asset].SomeObject would point to [Grouped Asset].SomeObject and changes from one would reflect at other.

Edited to include helper method described in comments:

```
static T CloneAndUpdate<T>(T t, Action<T> updater) where T: class
{
T clone = null; // Use reflection/serialization to create shallow/deep clone
updater(clone);
return clone;
}
```

Now, you may use the method as follows:

```
select Utility.CloneAndUpdate(ga.FirstOrDefault(), a =>
             {
                AssetId = ga.Key,
                Cost = ga.Select(gg=>gg.Cost).Sum()
             })
```

Comment: Oops! I notice that you want to use object initializers - not sure if they would work on Asset instance w/o using constructor.

Comment: Only way that I can think of is to add copy constructor that uses MemberwiseClone() - that will reduce at least time to write copy constructor.

Another way would be to write a static method such as --
static T CloneAndUpdate<T>(T t, Action<T> updater) where T: class
{
   T clone = ...; /* Use reflection/serialization to create clone */
   updater(clone);
   return clone;
} then use it as ----
select Utility.CloneAndUpdate(ga.FirstOrDefault(), a => {
  AssetId = ga.Key,
  Cost = ga.Select(gg=>gg.Cost).Sum()
})

Comment: hmm, last comment is a nice solution, could you post it as a answer please, it is little unreadable like this...thanx :)..oh, you did it already...ok thats it, thank you very much, I like your solution...+1 ;) and marked as answer :)